# The Crashlytics upload distribution task failed because it received invalid input

Tags: ant, jenkins, crashlytics

I am using ANT scripts and Jenkins for Android Crashlytics distribution purpose . But "crashlytics-upload-distribution" keep rejecting builds. I found following logs in console. Is there any way to debug further.

```
crashlytics-upload-distribution:
     [echo] Uploading /opt/dgmates/jenkins/workspace/staging-mobile-android-dg/dgmates/bin/dgmates-release.apk to Crashlytics...
     [java]  WARN - The upload distribution task failed because it received invalid input. Contact support@crashlytics.com for help.
     [java] Exception in thread "main" com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Distribution upload failed.
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:533)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgs(DeveloperTools.java:280)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.main(DeveloperTools.java:251)
     [java] Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.DistributionException: The upload distribution task failed because it received invalid input. Contact support@crashlytics.com for help.
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DistributionTasks.uploadDistribution(DistributionTasks.java:87)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:531)
     [java]     ... 2 more

BUILD FAILED
/opt/dgmates/jenkins/workspace/staging-mobile-android-wc/crashlytics/crashlytics_build_base.xml:107: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: The code seems to be closed-source, so in the absence of any other information, the easiest thing would be to contact support@crashlytics.com for help.